# How to move a file to another directory and write its filename to a file (create and append) within a loop in C# for SSIS Script Task?

Tags: c#, file, foreach, ssis, move

Below is the code that loops all the *.tar.gz files in the source directory. Each file is compared to both variables dayOld_7 and dayOld_14. If equal then set the dayOld_7 flag or the dayOld_14 flag to True. If the file is not one of them, the file has to be moved to another directory and write its filename to a file say ListOfMovedFiles.  How would I do that? I'm a newbie in C#.

```
    public void Main()
    {
        string dayOld_7 = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-7).ToString("yyyyMMdd") + ".tar";
        string dayOld_14 = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-14).ToString("yyyyMMdd") + ".tar";            
        string directoryPath = Dts.Variables["User::directoryPath"].Value.ToString();
        string[] sapFiles = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(directoryPath, "*.tar.gz");
        string currFile;

        foreach (string fName in sapFiles)
        {
            FileInfo fNameInfo = new FileInfo(fName);
            currFile = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(fNameInfo.FullName).ToString();

            if (currFile.Equals(dayOld_7))
            {
                Dts.Variables["User::Gzip_7"].Value = true;
            }
            else if (currFile.Equals(dayOld_14))
            {
                Dts.Variables["User::Gzip_14"].Value = true;
            }
            else if ( !(currFile.Equals(dayOld_7)) && !(currFile.Equals(dayOld_14)) )
            {
                //***What is the C# code to MOVE the file to a folder say C:/archive/ and write its filename to a file(create/append) ListOfMovedFiles.txt in the current directory?***
            }                 
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Start with the namespace:

```
using System.IO;
```

To move the file, it's pretty simple:

```
File.Move(sourceFilepath, destinationFilepath);
```

To write to a file, [taken from MS](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/816149?wa=wsignin1.0):

```
try 
{

  //Pass the filepath and filename to the StreamWriter Constructor
  StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter("C:\\Test.txt");

  //Write a line of text
  sw.WriteLine("Hello World!!");

  //Write a second line of text
  sw.WriteLine("From the StreamWriter class");

  //Close the file
  sw.Close();
}
catch(Exception e)
{
  Console.WriteLine("Exception: " + e.Message);
}
finally 
{
  Console.WriteLine("Executing finally block.");
}
```

Note: You can use CreateDirectory(dir) to create a directory, or if it already exists there is no harm in the command.

Comment: Thanks @sorrell! Just a follow up question: what is the difference between "C:\\Test.txt" and @"C:\Test.txt"?  I used a package variable say Dir with value "C:\Test" and it worked fine. I'm kind of confused. I'm sorry my background is Unix.

Comment: There is no difference in the end result.  The former is escaping the backslash and the latter is what's called a verbatim string literal, which is usually easier to read. [See here.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691090(v=vs.71).aspx)

Comment: string path = txtFilePath.Text;               
using(StreamWriter sw = File.AppendText(path))
{
  foreach (var line in employeeList.Items)                 
  {                    
    Employee e = (Employee)line; // unbox once
    sw.WriteLine(e.FirstName);                     
    sw.WriteLine(e.LastName);                     
    sw.WriteLine(e.JobTitle); 
  }                
} 
//I saw above code snippet to write (create/append) to a file. Are these two ways can do the same thing? What is the adv of each?